# Displaying String values on Y-axis using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am new to D3.js and got one issue.
I tried to create bar using some sample data.

```
 var data = [{"date":"Chennai","value":"53"},
            {"date":"Banglore","value":"165"},
            {"date":"Pune","value":"269"},
            {"date":"Ban","value":"344"},
            {"date":"Hyderabad","value":"376"},
            {"date":"HYd","value":"410"},
            {"date":"Gurugram","value":"421"},
            {"date":"Che","value":"376"}];
```

Able to display Strings(Ex: "Bangalore" on X-axis and values on Y-axis but I need to display Strings on Y-axis and values on X-axis.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 60},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([height,0]);

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);

var data = [{"date":"Chennai","value":"53"},
            {"date":"Banglore","value":"165"},
            {"date":"Pune","value":"269"},
            {"date":"Ban","value":"344"},
            {"date":"Hyderabad","value":"376"},
            {"date":"HYd","value":"410"},
            {"date":"Gurugram","value":"421"},
            {"date":"Kadapa","value":"405"},
            {"date":"Che","value":"376"}]

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(12);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return width - x(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.date); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
      .attr("title",function(d) { return y(d.value); });

      svg.selectAll("bar")          
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class","label")
      .attr("y", (function(d) { return y(d.date) + y.rangeBand()/2 ; }  ))
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) + 1; })
      .attr("dx", ".75em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.date; });
```

[image]

When I tried with the above code bars are coming as Horizontal but need as vertical.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question makes little sense: you said that you need a **vertical** bar chart, but you want to display the categories on the y axis and the values on the x axis. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be more accurate with your "height/x/y" manipulations :)

D3 uses coordinate space where x=0 and y=0 coordinates fall on the bottom left.

I've changed some of your code:
`svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x",function(d) { return x(d.value); }) 
      .attr("width", y.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y(d.date); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.date); })
      .attr("title",function(d) { return y(d.value); });`
and I've got the result 
[image]
Bars are in the right places.
I believe you can figure out with titles by your own, if no - you  know what to do

ps: http://jsfiddle.net/om42ts61/

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are dynamically appended it is better to use y-axis for the values.